# What is the equivalent of the SQL function REGEXP_EXTRACT in Azure Synapse?

Tags: regex, t-sql, azure-synapse, built-in, code-conversion

I want to convert my code that I was running in Netezza (SQL) to Azure Synapse (T-SQL). I was using the built-in Netezza SQL function REGEXP_EXTRACT but this function is not built-in Azure Synapse.

Here's the code I'm trying to convert

```
-- Assume that "column_v1" has datatype Character Varying(3) and can take value between 0 to 999 or NULL
SELECT
    column_v1
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_v1, '[0-9]+') as column_v2
FROM INPUT_TABLE
;
```

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

**`regexExtract()`** function is supported in Synapse.

In order to implement it, you need to use couple of things, here is a demo that i built, here im using the **SalesLT.Customer** data that is supported as a sample data in microsoft:

In Synapse -> Integrate tab:

1. Create new pipeline
2. Add dataflow activity to your pipline
3. In dataflow activity: under settings tab -> create new data flow
4. double click on the dataflow (it should open it) Add source (it can be blob storage / files on prem etc.)
5. add a derived column transformation
6. in derived column add new column (or override an existing column) in Expression: add this command `regexExtract(Phone,'(\\d{3})')`  it will select the 3 first digits, since my data has dashes in it, its makes more sense to replace all characters that are not digits using regexReplace method: `regexReplace(Phone,'[^0-9]', '')`
7. add sink

**DataFlow activities:**

[image]

**derived column transformation:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

please check MS docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions

Answer (score 0):

Regex_extract is not available in T-SQL. Thus, we try to do similar functionalities using Substring/left/right functions along with Patindex function

```
SELECT input='789A', 
extract= SUBSTRING('789A', PATINDEX('[0-9][0-9][0-9]', '789A'),4);
```

**Result**

[image]

Refer Microsoft documents [patindex (T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [substring (T-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for additional information.